# How replace item order in php array?

Tags: php, sorting

I asking about this case(replace item by position : highest with lowest etc.. ):

my inputs:

```
// case1:
array('orange','blue','red');

// case2:
array('orange','blue','red','white');
```

should get outputs:

```
// case1:
array('red','blue','orange');

// case2:
array('white','red','blue','orange');
```

its can be done by - but i am looking for more shorter way:

```
function myReplaceArr(array $arr){     
 $len=count($arr);  
 $loopLen=(int)($len/2);    
 for($i=0;$i<$loopLen;$i++){
   $temp=$arr[$i];
   $arr[$i]=$arr[$len-$i-1];
   $arr[$len-$i-1]=$temp;
 }
 return $arr;
}
var_export(myReplaceArr(array('orange','blue','red')));
var_export(myReplaceArr(array('orange','blue','red','white')));
```

Comment: Do you know what the correct order is ahead of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats called [array_reverse();](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

```
$array_1 = array('orange','blue','red');
$array_2 = array('orange','blue','red','white');

$array_1_new = array_reverse($array_1);
$array_2_new = array_reverse($array_2);
```

Answer (score 4):

The [list of array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) contains an [`array_reverse` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).

Answer (score 2):

What about [array_reverse()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_reverse()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

```
// case1:
    $array1 = array('orange','blue','red');
    $new_array1 = array_reverse($array1 );
    print_r($new_array1);
    Output: array('red','blue','orange');

// case2:
    $array2 = array('orange','blue','red','white');
    $new_array2 = array_reverse($array2 );
    print_r($new_array2);
    Output: array('white','red','blue','orange');
```